# Effects of microwaves on optical properties of human eye

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, microwaves

I have read a long series of paragraphs on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_radiation_and_health). Previously I thought that microwaves are not harmful  to living beings but Wiki does not claim this explicitly. while doing an experiment in my college laboratory our teacher cautioned us not to see the face of Horn antenna. He said it will damage eyes so I am asking here to be sure about that.

> What are the effects of microwaves emitted by Horn antenna upon the optical properties of human eye(a natural optical device)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology (at least the first part).

Comment: It's off topic to ask about safety issues, or whether you should worry about something, but we could address a question about dielectric heating; for example, something about how to calculate the amount of energy transferred might be appropriate.

Comment: And to calculate the heating you should provide more information. Power of the source, distance, etc. Although I think it will be like 0.0001ºC.

Comment: See [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94322/what-would-give-us-more-heat-infrared-or-microwaves/94326#94326) and the links within it

Comment: To make the question on-topic you should remove 1) and 2) (and probably 3)).

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12069/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I _think_ all of this except point 4 is still off topic.

Comment: @DavidZ Point _4_ seems appropriate. I'll ask on meta .

Comment: Yeah, that might be a good idea.

Comment: I have edited my question from a long time. Please tell me why it is off topic.

Comment: These are still two questions.

Comment: @jinawee I have deleted one of the questions and asked it separately.

Comment: @DavidZ, my question has been reworded. Would you reconsider my question.